# Requery a subform from another form from a navigation Form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a problem with refreshing a subform from another form in navigation form
Here it is:

I have a form called MainForm in it is one sub form called MainSubForm..
From the link in a row in MainSubForm if you click it will open the third form like popup called ClientForm that will show the details of client on row selected on MainSubForm. Till here is everything ok, but in popup ClientForm form I have to edit some data, clos ClientForm and refresh the MainSubForm.
My code in ClientForm is like this:

```
Forms.MainForm.MainSubForm.Form.Requery

DoCmd.Close
```

When I open the MainForm normally it is work perfect, but when I open the MainForm form from my Navigation Form it is not working.

Info:  I have navigation form that I put all my forms that i needet in there (  MainSubForm not in navigation form )

Thanx in advance,

Comment: I am confused. MainSubForm is or is not embedded in Navigation form? By open 'normally' you mean as standalone form? What do you mean by 'open the MainForm form from my Navigation Form' - there is code in Navigation Form to open MainForm (show code)? MainForm is NOT a Navigation Form? Images might be helpful.

Comment: 1.Yes, MainSubForm is embedded in MainForm and this two together in Navigation form.
2. _By open 'normally' you mean as standalone form?_  Yes I mean when I open MainForm from **Forms** in access  3.  _What do you mean by 'open the MainForm form from my Navigation Form_    I mean when I open MainForm from tab on navigation form. 4. _MainForm is NOT a Navigation Form_  i was my mistake, I wanted to say ClientForm  is not in navigation form but it is no sot important.  Thanx

Comment: So MainForm is actually located on the tab of a Navigation form named **Navigation Form**? in which case MainForm is no longer a 'main form'. And then MainSubForm is a subform on Main Form? Could really give forms better names. Again, pictures might help. Edit your question.

Comment: OK I will try to be more specific 1. _So MainForm is actually located on the tab of a Navigation form named Navigation Form_ ,  Yes exactly, but tab name is **Tikets** but it doesn't matter. In this tab  also is SubForm  (MainSubForm) embedded  in MainForm. So when I cliclk in SubForm in a row named "Edit" ,it will open one PopUp Form called  ClientForm, after in popUp ClientForm  I made some changes and save and clos ClientForm and I need also to requere (refresh) SubForm  (MainSubForm) to show the changes  what I made in ClientForm.. That is ALL

Comment: Then if MainForm is now embedded on another form object, of course the referencing must change to include that form (**Navigation Form**). Why don't you just do client edits on the subform instead of opening up a popup form?

Comment: _Why don't you just do client edits on the subform instead of opening up a popup form?_  Because there are different tables, they must to calculate something..  _Then if MainForm is now embedded on another form object, of course the referencing must change to include that form (Navigation Form)_ i put reference like this  ' Forms.NavigationForm.MainForm.MainSubForm.Form.Requery '    but is not working

Comment: @june7  Here is an image of program may be it can help

[Here is a image][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrKNz.png

Comment: Again, should edit question. Try this EXACT code: `Forms![Navigation Form].NavigationSubform.Requery`. Tested and to my surprise works. The subform is requeried.

Comment: OK ,now it is working finaly , The code is like this:  `Forms![Navigation Form].NavigationSubform.Form.MainSubForm_Ds.Form.Requery` 
Thanx a lot for your hepl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you retain the default names assigned by Access (**Navigation Form** and **NavigationSubform**), the following should work to requery form/subform placed on Navigation Form (it does for me).

`Forms![Navigation Form].NavigationSubform.Requery`

Comment: Ok your code is like that `Forms![Navigation Form].NavigationSubform.Requery`     , so what I must put in `[Navigation Form]` exactly the name of navigation form or to leave like this, and what to put in  `NavigationSubform`

Comment: Do exactly as I stated. If you retain the default names Access assigns, use them - exactly as in my answer. If you changed the default names then use what you changed to. Did you try?

Comment: Yes and it is not working, it says:  `cannot find the reference from 'Navigation form' . `

Comment: OK ,now it is working finaly , The code is like this: `Forms![Navigation Form].NavigationSubform.Form.MainSubForm_Ds.Form.Requery` Thanx a lot for your hep

Comment: Glad you got it figured out; however, that is more path reference than required for my form.